# How can split order in magento1

Tags: magento-1.9

I want split order from cart items, for example if anyone add to cart any product then in cart, there is two item added in my website. first is main item in cart and second is security deposit item, so when we do place order then order will be split and in payment method(authorized.net) - payment should be initialised for both order.
Please help me for that, anyone have idea for that

Comment: anyone have idea about that?